# how to run a applet program from a JFrame application?

Tags: java, applet, jframe

I am having a JFrame application which is running fine.
Now I want to call a applet program from that JFrame application and I don't know how to do it.

Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to add the applet in JFrame. Applet is nothing but the component. You can add it in any of the JFrame component.

```
myPanel.add(myApplet);
```